# Diseñador de informes web open source nodejs, angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, web, report, reporte

Estoy empezando a incursionar en el desarrollo web con Angular y Nodejs, me gustaría saber el mejor camino para crear reportes empresariales con un diseñador gráfico al estilo de devexpress.  Lo necesito para crear facturas y reportes contables y no sé que diseñador de reportes utilizar y ojalá sea preferiblemente gratuito.

No tengo muy claro como enlazar mi aplicación front-end con angular con un reporte web.

Si alguien me puede dar una guía estaría muy agradecido.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @juan-carlos, te invito a leer [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Si ya has intentado y tienes algo de código sería bueno que lo publiques, las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta en cualquier momento para agregar más información.

Comment: Tengo años trabajando angular y no he visto nada como lo que comentas, lo mas parecido es un wysiwyg editor, pero tu tienes que generar todo,  la otra opción es que generes en el servidor

Comment: encontraste solucion? tal vez puedas crear tu reporte en HTML con alguna herramienta como DreamWeaber y luego renderizarlo a pdf con nodejs